# mysql install problems

Tags: mysql

My MySQL is not working. I have recently reinstalled windows 7 on my machine and want to install Mysql and phpMyAdmin, but I fail already at Mysql.

the service won't start and the error file is showing this info:

```
100912 11:36:28 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
100912 11:36:28  InnoDB: Log file .\ib_logfile0 did not exist: new to be created
InnoDB: Setting log file .\ib_logfile0 size to 24 MB
InnoDB: Database physically writes the file full: wait...
100912 11:36:29  InnoDB: Log file .\ib_logfile1 did not exist: new to be created
InnoDB: Setting log file .\ib_logfile1 size to 24 MB
InnoDB: Database physically writes the file full: wait...
InnoDB: Cannot initialize created log files because
InnoDB: data files are corrupt, or new data files were
InnoDB: created when the database was started previous
InnoDB: time but the database was not shut down
InnoDB: normally after that.
100912 11:36:29 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' init function returned error.
100912 11:36:29 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' registration as a STORAGE ENGINE failed.
100912 11:36:29 [ERROR] Unknown/unsupported table type: INNODB
100912 11:36:29 [ERROR] Aborting

100912 11:36:29 [Note] C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.1\bin\mysqld: Shutdown complete
```

I have configured Mysql with the following:

```
developer machine
Multifunctional db
storage path = Installation Path
dessision support (dss/olap)
enable tcp/ip
enable strict mode
character set = utf8 ( i'm from sweden and neeed å ä ö)
include bin dir in path
enable root acces from remot machines
```

please try to help me I have had this problem for a whole day now...

Comment: Probably it's an UAC issue (did you run with administrative rights?), since you're installing to `C:\Program Files`. See what happens when you install to another directory, e.g. to `C:\Foobar\MySQL`. If it works fine, then it's got to do with file permissions.

Comment: I have disabled UAC, and I only have one account on my computer - the administrator account. but I'll try to install it elsewhere..

Comment: Hey it worked.. I installed at c:\mysql insteed..
Now my problem is phpMyAdmin. I have unrared it in my localhost root, and I browsed to "localhost/setup/index.php", created a new server. The only thing I filled in was my mysql password..
Then I browsed to "localhost/index.php" typed in "root" as user and my MySQL password as password and got an error message back saying
#2002 can not log onto the MySQL-server

Comment: and thx for the fast answer stakx!!